# Failed: Cannot read property 'UserName' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, typescript, selenium-webdriver, protractor, e2e-testing

config.ts

```
[
 {
 "UserName": "test@cda.en",
 "Password": "test"
 }
]
```

Fragment protractor.conf.js

```
exports.config = {
allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
specs: [
'./e2e/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
],
```

Method login

```
login() { 
 element(by.name('username')).sendKeys(browser.params[0].UserName);
 element(by.name('password')).sendKeys(browser.params[0].Password);
}
```

In the log I get:
 Failed: Cannot read property 'UserName' of undefined

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

you want to send global parameters. 
then call the method

```
 element(by.name('username')).sendKeys(browser.params[0].UserName);
    exports.config = {
        // ...

        params: {
            UserName: 'test'
        }

        // ...
    };
```

Comment: Maybe I have to reference somehow to the config.ts file in the app.po.ts file containing the login () method.?